# Get JSON URL in raw format online

Tags: java, android, json, amazon-web-services, web-services

Using gist.github.com, I am able to get JSON in raw form. However, when I edit the code, the url of the raw format changes. Can you suggest me a website which can do this bit for me? I would like to have a constant URL of my JSON code which I can edit it and have changes live on the same link.

```
{
    "error": false,
    "products": [
      {
    "name": "spiderman",
    "image": "insert image link here"
    },
    {
    "name": "superman",
    "image": "insert image link here"
    },
    {
    "name": "batman",
    "image": "insert image link here"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your question.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aniketraj1947/28d29ad35a7874cbb46a67a17195ccf4/edit

Go to the above link, when you click raw, you can get the code in raw form. However when you edit it and publish then the url changes. I want to have my json raw code live with a constant url and I can edit it time to time. Which web service can do this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Url of gist changes with every version , if you want the url to stay constant

Try

https://jsonblob.com/

paste your response and save it will give url , just bookmark the url

get id from url and paste it in following url

https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/YOUR_ID

it will give raw response

Or else better get your own hosting , it will be good and more customizable

**for your response**

for changing data use

https://jsonblob.com/aa1ada56-6aed-11e8-b292-634b403e9ce7

for getting raw response use

https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/aa1ada56-6aed-11e8-b292-634b403e9ce7

Comment: It is not providing a raw format of json in URL. How would I parse it in android? I need a raw format

Comment: Example https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aniketraj1947/28d29ad35a7874cbb46a67a17195ccf4/raw/baa42699a68f0230fee8991ffb9860ba9da3b18d/testing

Comment: Just a sec you need to use its Api url with your id , i will update the answer